# Proof by Induction $4^n \geq 16n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that for an integer $n \geq 4$, $4^n \geq 16n^2$

Base Case:

For $n = 4$,

$4^4 \geq 16(4)^2$

$256 = 256$

Induction Hypothesis:

Suppose this statement hold up to $4^k > 16k^2$

Then:

$4^{(k+1)} = 4\cdot4^k$

Now I am not sure if what I did so far is correct and what to do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach so far is great.

Now, with your induction hypothesis $4^k \geq 16k^2$, you need to show that $4^{k+1} \geq 16(k+1)^2$.

Comment: Okay, I think what I am about to type is correct then

For k>=4,

(k+1)^2/k^2 = (1+1/k)^2 <= (5/4)^2 < 2^2 = 4.

Therefore

4^(k+1) = 4*4k >= 4*16k^2 > [(k+1)^2/k^2]*16k^2 = 16(k+1)^2.

Comment: You should format your posts using LaTeX (put mathematical expressions inside dollar-signs \$...\$), that makes them much easier to read. But if you have shown that the new expression is true, based on the induction hypothesis, you have succeded.

Answer (score 0):

What you did so far is correct. What you have to do next is to evaluate also the right hand side of the inequality for $k+1$ and compare.